# "register" to asterisk with any password

Tags: asterisk

I have set up an asterisk server on a non-important VPS to test something; there is no sip trunk, so it can't call anywhere.

I see a lot of attempts to register; I'd like to allow them to register to see what they want to do (honeypot). Is that possible, or should I just put in some easy passwords?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to monitor.  When you say there is no SIP trunk, you realize that a SIP stack is required for calls/registrations inbound too?  (If you are using 'freepbx' terminology then the SIP stack is active, just not configured.  If you are using 'asterisk' terminology then you have excluded SIP channel from being compiled and is therefor SIP not running)

You can allow guest access in sip.conf, or just create a bunch of extensions where the password is the same as the extension (eg: 100 / 100).  The freePBX equivalent settings can be found in extensions and SIP options.

If you want to see the results of such a SIP honeypot experiment look at [Telium Honeypot Experiment](http://telium.ca/?honeypot1)

Comment: What I mean by "no SIP trunk" is that there is no connection to a provider, even if they can get in, they can call nowhere to the ordinary PSTN network, so they can call nowhere. So it can't cost me any money.

Comment: In that case my answer above will due what you want: enable guest, setup extensions with un/pw matching (eg: 100/100)